# Git - Custom Merge Driver to ignore files

Tags: git

I want Git to ignore certain config files during merge. I tried updating git attributes by changing the merge strategy to 'ours' as below. But this works only if there is a merge conflict.
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies

I would like not even auto merging happen on these files. So I want to write a custom merge driver. Is it possible with custom merge driver to stop automatic merging on these files? I was not able to find good resource on how to write custom merge driver. What arguments does the driver receive.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving a direct answer to this question, i'll try to give an answer to the problem you are having, instead of an answer about the solution you are trying to implement.

This often is a sign of an issue with the way you use git. Often people run into this problem because they are using git to deploy their code, and want different configurationt files for different deployment targets.

It often is beter to alter the way you work slightly in order to prevent these kind of issues. [Here](https://gist.github.com/canton7/1423106) is a list of different proven solutions to these kind of problems.

It comes down to using different files for different deployment targets. For example, don't track the actual config file, but track a config template. That way, you can change the actual config file, without git needing to track those changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want git to ignore changes in some tracked files.

If so try:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

If you wanna start tracking changes again run the following command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

You can also remove the files from `git` and have them ignored (via `.gitignore`), since it sounds like you misuse `git` in order to track these config files.

Comment: By passing update-index --assume-unchaged, you promise git the file won't change. By changing the file, you are then breaking the promise. This will lead to problems when checking out other branches.

Comment: You are correct with the checking out, as for the *promise* you are not. The `--assume-unchanged` is not a promise as much as a request from git to ignore changes in a tracked file (by that actually promising it *would* change). And with my answer I obviously assume there are no changes to these files from another source, preventing the checking out issues.

Comment: You are actually saying git can safely assume that the file is unchanged. When the file *does* change, this leads to problems when git needs to alter the file.

Comment: I agree. As I said I assume there are no changes to these files in the repo, and in my answer I also said it is probably a misuse of git.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that using --assume-unchanged is not without issues, and should be used very rarely.